# multiple prices of product based on countries/regions

Tags: products-management

I have a question.

I want to have different prices of a product belonging to different countries. Means different boxes of prices for different locations. Suppose I add product having different prices for UK and US, then if a customer visits the website from UK it will have different price than what another customer would have visited the same website from US.

How to achieve this? Can you guys point me in the right direction?

**P.S.**  It should not be multiple sites. It MUST MUST be only single store.

Comment: If you consider multiple stores then here is a paid extension: **http://shop.spletnisistemi.si/en/magento-different-price-for-different-store-view.html**

Comment: thanks Shatir but it should be in the single website

Comment: It would be a single website, only multiple stores.

Comment: Hi Shatir. I have updated my question. It should be only single store single website and a facility to have feature mentioned  in my question.

Comment: Multiple store views is the way to do this. And the free extension in @user2157 answer makes it a breeze. Do you understand store views, why have you ruled that out?

Comment: McNab, I do understand store views. I can't implement that way. What client says I have to do.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same requirement a few weeks back. Instead of reinventing the wheel I've used this extension which does exactly what you need.

[Advanced Pricing](http://innoexts.com/promotion/advanced-pricing/#.UdQJDj6gkTc)